# MessageHub - Data Encryption at rest

Tags: encryption, ibm-cloud, message-hub

we need to understand if Bluemix MessageHub supports data encryption at rest. If it does not offer direct support for data encryption at rest, are there any best practices to implement this from a consumer or producer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the disks that contain data for Message Hub are encrypted.